# Recording video & audio data from RTSP stream using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to record video data using FFMPEG. I have used following commands

> ffmpeg -i 'rtsp://..' -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 3600 -y file.mp4

I got the following error

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00

(180000/1) -> 90000.00 (180000/2)
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.17.8.138:554/h264.sdp?res=half&x0=0&y0=0&x1=1280&   

y1=1024&
qp=20&doublescan=0&bitrate=65535&ssn=20':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0.0: Video: h264, yuv420p, 640x512, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'file.mp4':
Stream #0.0: Video: 0x0000, yuv420p, 640x512, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop encoding
[NULL @ 0x84c16d0]error, non monotone timestamps 50 >= 50
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Error while opening file
```

Can any body help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

These parts of the pasted output:

```
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://10.17.8.138:554/h264.sdp
[...]
Output #0, mp4, to 'file.mp4':
Stream #0.0: Video: 0x0000, yuv420p, 640x512, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
```

tell me that the FFmpeg installation does not know how to encode H.264 video. This is likely because libx264 support was not built in. Run:

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep libx264
```

to see if support is present. If not, rebuild with libx264 support and try again.